# Can you connect to more tables with the same data connector in Lookerstudio?

Tags: mysql, connector, looker-studio

I'm using Looker Studio and connect to my MySQL source via the standard connect. I have data in several tables in the database and was wondering if I can make use of the same connection to reach all the tables or I need to make a separate connection per table I would like to use?

Thanks for the simple question

I have tried various options but it only allows me to select one table in the connector wizard

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you need a configurable connector that supports all the tables you need. This connector must be designed using configuration parameters. You have to use this connection on multiple datasources by setting up a table for each of them. Post as a comment since I have just started studying looker connectors and not sure about that